# javascript snippet- Use the .env File-feecodecamp

Tags: javascript

Why the first snippet doesn't work, but the second one can work correctly?
Thanks.

```
var response;
if (process.env.MESSAGE_STYLE == "uppercase") {
    response = "HELLO JSON";
  } else {
    response = "Hello json";
  }
app.get("/json",(req, res)=>(res.json({message:response})));
```

```
// app.get('/json', function (req, res) {
//     if (process.env.MESSAGE_STYLE == "uppercase") {
//         res.json({ "message": "HELLO JSON" })
//     } else {
//         res.json({ "message": "Hello json" })
//     }
// })
```

Why the first snippet doesn't work, but the second one can work correctly?
Thanks.

Comment: What does not work? What's the actual behavior and what's the expected behavior?